# How to use shared pointer as a function argument

Tags: c++, c++11

With traditional pointers i can use them in the following way.

```
int value;

void setValue(int* val)
{
  *val = 5;
}

SetValue(&value);
```

Can i do the same thing with shared Pointer ?

Comment: What do you mean by "same thing".  The answer is "you can", but I'm not sure what analog of a pointer you feel you can't do with a shared_ptr ?  Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Can i pass shared_ptr<int> instead of int*

Comment: It appears you are looking for guidance on when to use shared_ptr as a parameter.  A coworker wrote up a nice article on when/how/why to use shared_ptr, references, pointers, and unique_ptr:  https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) method on shared_ptr to return underlying raw pointer.

Example:

```
shared_ptr<int> value;

void setValue(int* val)
{
  *val = 5;
}

SetValue(value.get());
```

Or this:

```
shared_ptr<int> value;

void setValue(shared_ptr<int>& v)
{
    int* ptr = v.get();
    *ptr = 5;
}

SetValue(value);
```

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59710179/how-to-use-shared-pointer-as-a-function-argument/59710252#comment105572329_59710179) clarifies OP's intention. `get()` is not required at all. Because the underlying pointer related operators are overloaded.

Comment: @iammilind - I interpret the OP as saying, "I've got a function that takes a raw pointer as a parameter, but all I have is a shared_ptr."  He just needs to invoke get() and make assurances that whatever he passes that pointer to doesn't get cached or held.  His SetValue example meets this criteria.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i do the same thing with shared Pointer?

**No**. It may lead to undefined behavior or crash if done incorrectly.

If you pass `&val` to below function:

```
void setValue(shared<int> val)  // `int*` replaced by `shared_ptr<int>`
```

then at the end of the function, `val`'s destructor `~shared_ptr` will be called, which will `delete` a memory location, which was not created by `new`. To avoid that, you may have to provide a custom deleter.

I don't think you want to get into that. :-)

---

For better coding practice in such cases, pass by reference so that you make less mistakes and don't have to worry about freeing up memory.

```
void setValue(int& val)  // simply pass `setValue(value)`
```

Used smart pointers only when you use memory from free store such as `new`.